# android browsers limitations for HTML & CSS

Tags: android, html, css, browser

i designed a website with this address : http://www.milanmobl.ir

in android tablets browsers this site have some problems

for example :

i think some divs with `margin:0 auto` aren't centered in page

i want to know is there any **HTML** or **CSS** limitaions for android browsers?

**Notes :**

Android Version : 4

Browser : FireFox (Last Version)

my css file :

```
@font-face
{  
    font-family: nassim;  
    src: url("../Fonts/nassim.eot"); /* IE */
    src: local("real_nassim"), url("../Fonts/nassim.ttf") format("truetype"); /* non-IE */  
}
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size:small;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
a,input,select,textarea,#menu li a,span
{
    transition:all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s;
    -o-transition:all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition:all 0.5s;
}
body{
    background-color:#5c4026;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
}
#wrapper{
    width:100%;
}
#nav{
    background-color:#eae4df;
}
#nav .main{
    width:940px;
    height:55px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#nav .main .info{
    width:740px;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
}
#nav .main .info span{
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:16px;
    direction:rtl;
    color:#ac8665;
    margin:7.5px 0;
    border-right:1px dotted #999592;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px white;
    -moz-text-shadow:1px 1px 1px white;
    -webkit-text-shadow:1px 1px 1px white;
}
#nav .main .email{
    background:url(../images/email.png) no-repeat 90% 50%;
    padding:0 50px 0 20px;
}
#nav .main .mobile{
    background:url(../images/mobile.png) no-repeat 90% 50%;
    padding:0 30px 0 20px;
}
#nav .main .search{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}
#nav .main .search div{
    background-color:#d8d0c9;
    height:30px;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    direction:rtl;
    margin:12.5px 0;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:0 0 2px #999999 inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 2px #999999 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 2px #999999 inset;
}
#keyword{
    width:140px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
}
#searchbtn{
    background-color:#81572d;
    color:white;
    border:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
#head{
    background:url(../images/header-bg.jpg) repeat-x;
    height:545px;
}
#head .main{
    background:url(../images/halo.png) no-repeat;
    width:1200px;
    height:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    direction:rtl;
    text-align:center;
}
#head .main .logo{
    height:239px;
    background:url(../images/logo.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#menu{
    position:relative;
    width:912px;
    height:47px;
    background:url(../images/menu-bg.png) no-repeat;
    direction:rtl;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:100;
}
#menu a{
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:nassim !important;
    font-size:20px !important;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px Black;
    -moz-text-shadow:1px 1px 1px Black;
    -webkit-text-shadow:1px 1px 1px Black;
}
#menu:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding:0 38px 0 0;
}
#menu li:hover > ul{ display: block }
#menu ul li:hover{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 100%),url(../images/menu-br.png) no-repeat right center; /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.2))),url(../images/menu-br.png) no-repeat right center; /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 100%),url(../images/menu-br.png) no-repeat right center; /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),url(../images/menu-br.png) no-repeat right center; /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),url(../images/menu-br.png) no-repeat right center; /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),url(../images/menu-br.png) no-repeat right center; /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='rgba(0,0,0,0.2)', endColorstr='rgba(0,0,0,0)',GradientType=0 ),url(../images/menu-br.png) no-repeat right center; /* IE6-9 */
}
#menu ul li:hover > a{
    color:#ffde97;
}
#menu ul li{
    background:url(../images/menu-br.png) no-repeat right center;
    color:white;
    padding:5.5px 30px;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    direction:rtl;
}
#menu ul li:first-child{
    background:none;
}
#menu ul li:first-child:hover{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.2))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='rgba(0,0,0,0.2)', endColorstr='rgba(0,0,0,0)',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
#menu ul ul{
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-85px;
    position: absolute;
    padding:10px 0 0 0;
    top: 35px;
    display:none;
    z-index:1000;
}
#menu ul li ul li{
    width:150px;
    background: url(../images/menu-hr.png) no-repeat center top;
    background-color: #7c030c;
    border-radius:0;
    -moz-border-radius:0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0;
    padding:5px 10px;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
}
#menu ul li ul li:hover{
    background: url(../images/menu-hr.png) no-repeat center top;
    background-color: #70020a;
}
#menu ul li ul li a{
    color:white;
    font-size:16px !important;
}
#menu ul li ul li:first-child{
    background: none;
    background-color: #7c030c;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
}
#menu ul li > ul:before{
    /*triangle*/
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:75px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #70020a;
}
#menu ul li ul li:first-child:hover{
    background-color: #70020a;
}
#menu ul li ul li:last-child{
    border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
}
#menu ul li ul li:only-child{
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
#menu ul ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
    padding:0px;
}
#pat1{
    background:url(../images/pat1.jpg) repeat-x;
    height:130px;
}
#pat2{
    background:url(../images/pat2.jpg) repeat-x;
    height:84px;
    margin-top:-115px;
}
#main{
    background-color:#c2b5a4;
}
#main .main{
    width:940px;
    min-height:461px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#main .body{
    position:relative;
    background-color:#ece3dc;
    margin-top:-429px;
    padding-top:45px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
}
#main .box{
    background:url(../images/tazhib1.jpg) no-repeat center top, url(../images/tazhib2.jpg) no-repeat left center;
    width:880px;
    min-height:255px;
    padding:20px;
    margin:10px auto;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid #ddcec2;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
#main .box .pic{
    border:5px solid #c1b8b1;
    float:right;
    max-width: 220px;
}
#main .box h2{
    color:#996600;
    float:left;
    width: 640px;
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family:nassim !important;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#main .box p{
    color:#333333;
    font-family:Tahoma !important;
    font-size:11.5px !important;
    float:left;
    width: 640px;
    text-align: justify;
    direction: rtl;
}
#main .box2{
    background:url(../images/tazhib1.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    width:880px;
    min-height:255px;
    padding:20px;
    margin:10px auto;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid #ddcec2;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
#main .box2 .pic{
    border:5px solid #c1b8b1;
    float:right;
}
#main .box2 h2{
    color:#996600;
    float:left;
    width: 640px;
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family:nassim !important;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#main .box2 p{
    color:#333333;
    font-family:Tahoma !important;
    font-size:11.5px !important;
    float:left;
    width: 640px;
    text-align: justify;
    direction: rtl;
}
#main .box3{
    position:relative;
    background:url(../images/tazhib4.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    width:258px;
    height:298px;
    float:left;
    direction:rtl;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 20px 20px 20px;
    margin:10px 0 10px 10px;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid #ddcec2;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
#main .box3 .pic{
    width:250px;
    height:100px;
    border:5px solid #c1b8b1;
}
#main .box3 h3{
    color:#996600;
    text-align: center;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family:nassim !important;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#main .box3 p{
    color:#777777;
    font-family:Tahoma !important;
    font-size:11px !important;
    text-align: justify;
    direction: rtl;
}
#main .box3 a.more{
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    color:#a80000;
    font-family:Tahoma !important;
    font-size:12px !important;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
    float: left;
}
.box3 .bottom .subscribe form{
    margin-top:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
.box3 .subscribe img{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.box3 .subscribe input[type=text]{
    width:220px;
    height:30px;
    color:#777777;
    background-color:#efe9e4;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Tahoma !important;
    font-size:11px !important;
    border:1px solid #e1d2c6;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    padding:0;
    margin:3px;
}
.box3 .subscribe input[type=submit]{
    width:70px;
    height:30px;
    color:white;
    background-color:#9d1317;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #d32731 0%, #9d1317 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#d32731), color-stop(100%,#9d1317)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #d32731 0%,#9d1317 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #9d1317 0%,#d32731 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #9d1317 0%,#d32731 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #9d1317 0%,#d32731 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9d1317', endColorstr='#d32731',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    text-align:center;
    font-size:16px !important;
    text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000;
    -moz-text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000;
    -webkit-text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000;
    border:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    margin:3px;
}
#main .box4{
    background:url(../images/tazhib1.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    width:880px;
    min-height:255px;
    padding:20px;
    margin:10px auto;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid #ddcec2;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
#main .box4 h2{
    color:#996600;
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family:nassim !important;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#main .box4 p{
    color:#333333;
    font-family:Tahoma !important;
    font-size:11.5px !important;
    text-align: justify;
    direction: rtl;
}
#main #slider{
    width:900px;
    height:290px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px auto;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid #ddcec2;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
#main .newest_products{
    width:920px;
    height:178px;
    background:url(../images/tazhib3.jpg) no-repeat center bottom white;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid #ddcec2;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
#main #carousel{
    width:920px;
    height:178px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#main #carousel .img{
    position:relative;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
    padding:0px;
}
#main #carousel .img div{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
    display:none;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:80px;
    -moz-border-radius:80px;
    -webkit-border-radius:80px;
}
#main #carousel .content{
    background-color:black;
}
#main #carousel img{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border:5px solid #c1b8b1;
    border-radius:80px;
    -moz-border-radius:80px;
    -webkit-border-radius:80px;
}
#main #carousel .span{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display: block;
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
    line-height:160px;
}
.bt{
    background-color:#870d0d;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    border:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
.bt2{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    left:92px;
    background-color:#870d0d;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    border:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
.globe{
    background: url(../images/globe.png) no-repeat right 5px center;
}
.cart{
    background: url(../images/cart.png) no-repeat right 5px center;
}
.layer{
    background: url(../images/layer.png) no-repeat right 5px center;
}
#main .main .margin{
    width:100%;
    height:110px;
}
#footer{
    background:url(../images/footer-bg.jpg) repeat-x;
    height:409px;
}
#footer .bg{
    background:url(../images/footer.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    width:1200px;
    height:409px;
    margin:0 auto;
    direction:rtl;
}
#footer .main{
    width:940px;
    height:409px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#footer .columns{
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    width:940px;
    height:320px;
}
#footer .right{
    width:290px;
    height:290px;
    float:left;
    padding:20px 5px;
    background:url(../images/vline.png) no-repeat left center;
}
#footer .center{
    width:290px;
    height:290px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
    background:url(../images/vline.png) no-repeat left center;
    padding:20px 5px;
    direction:rtl;
}
#footer .center h3{
    font-family:nassim !important;
    font-size:20px !important;
}
#footer .center a{
    color:white;
    text-shadow:0 0 2px black;
    -moz-text-shadow:0 0 2px black;
    -webkit-text-shadow:0 0 2px black;
}
#footer .center a:hover{
    color:yellow;
}
#footer .center ul li{
    width:252px;
    background:url(../images/list.png) no-repeat right center;
    padding:9px 17px;
    text-align:right;
}
#footer .center ul li:hover{
    background:url(../images/list-hover.png) no-repeat right center;
}
#footer .center p{
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}
#footer .center p a{
    color:yellow;
}
#footer .center p a:hover{
    color:orange;
}
#footer .left{
    width:290px;
    height:290px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
    padding:20px 5px;
    direction:rtl;
}
#footer .left div{
    display:block;
}
#footer .left p{
    color:white;
    padding:0 5px;
    text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000;
    -moz-text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000;
    -webkit-text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000;
}
#footer .left .bold{
    font-weight:bold;
}
#footer .left .leftalign{
    text-align:left;
    direction:ltr;
    float:left;
}
#footer .left .rightalign{
    text-align:right;
    direction:rtl;
    display:inline-block;
}
#footer .left h3, #footer .center h3, #footer .right h3{
    color:white;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
.hline{
    height:1px;
    background:url(../images/hline.png) no-repeat center center;
    margin:10px auto;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}

.dashed{
    height:1px;
    border-bottom:1px dashed #5a451a;
    margin:5px auto;
}
.infoDiv{
    display:inline-block;
    height:30px;
    background:url(../images/double-dotted.png) repeat-x right bottom;
    text-align:right;
    direction:rtl;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.keywordsDiv{
    /*text-align:justify;*/
    text-align:right;
    direction:rtl;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.date{
    background:url(../images/date.png) no-repeat right center;
    color:#C0C0C0;
    padding:0 20px 0 0;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.visits{
    background:url(../images/view.png) no-repeat right center;
    color:#C0C0C0;
    padding:0 20px 0 0;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.comment{
    background:url(../images/comment.png) no-repeat right center;
    color:#C0C0C0;
    padding:0 20px 0 0;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.keywords{
    background:url(../images/keywords.png) no-repeat right center;
    color:#40a1ce !important;
    padding:0 25px 0 0;
}
.tags{
    background-color:#d6d6d6;
    color:#b3b3b3 !important;
    padding:2px 3px;
    margin:1.5px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.tags:hover{
    background-color:#898989;
    color:#white !important;
}
.keywordsDiv a {
    display: inline-block;
}
.left_box .body ul li {
    width:100%;
    background:url(../images/double-dotted.png) repeat-x right bottom;
    float:left;
    padding:9px 0px;
    text-align:right;
    direction:rtl;
}
.left_box .body ul li:last-child {
    background:none;
}
.left_box .body ul li a {
    color:#555555;
    text-align:right;
    direction:rtl;
}
.left_box .body ul li a:hover {
    color:#0099ff;
}
.left_box .body ul li img {
    width:80px;
    border:5px solid #a2a2a2;
    float:right;
    margin-left:10px;
    transition:all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s;
    -o-transition:all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition:all 0.5s;
}
.left_box .body ul li a:hover > img{
    border:5px solid #0099cc;
}

.gallery{
    width:860px;
    height:350px;
    background-color:#6b5441;
    margin:30px auto;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
#contact_form{
    width:550px;
    height:170px;
    background-color:#dcdcdc;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
#contact_form .title2{
    font-size:13px !important;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px white !important;
    -moz-text-shadow:1px 1px 1px white !important;
    -webkit-text-shadow:1px 1px 1px white !important;
}
#contact_form p{
    text-align:justify !important;
    font-family:Tahoma !important;
    font-size:11px !important;
}
#contact_form table{
    width:100%;
}
#contact_form input[type=text]{
    width:170px;
    height:25px;
    padding:0 2px;
    text-align:right;
    direction:rtl;
    font-family:Tahoma !important;
    font-size:11px !important;
    color:#afafaf;
    border:1px solid #afafaf;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
#contact_form textarea{
    width:363px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:right;
    direction:rtl;
    font-family:Tahoma !important;
    font-size:11px !important;
    margin:4px;
    color:#afafaf;
    border:1px solid #afafaf;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    resize:none;
}
#contact_form input[type=submit] {
    position:relative;
    top:-37px;
    left:-465px;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Tahoma !important;
    font-size:11px !important;
    background-color:#0087c7;
    color:white;
    border:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
```

Comment: please give more information, what browser, what version of android, images of expected and actual pages, etc.

Comment: Don't have an actual tablet, but my phone is in tablet mode and just tested with Chrome and Dolphin and it worked fine. So I'm guessing it's a problem with the tablet or firefox. Most likely it's just some problem with your css for tablets...

Comment: no problem, if you post your css and the images I can take a look

Comment: ...and a screenshot from your tablet?

Comment: i have no tablet like you :) i saw that in my ferind's tablet

Comment: With no images, I can't solve this. Please mark my answer correct below as I don't think it is a solvable problem, if you can't replicate it

Comment: give me an up vote first :))))))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no problems from an Android tablet, more than likely it is a browser-specific or a screen size based issue. Without images of the problem it is near impossible to solve.

Comment: i think it is screen size based issue too

Comment: checked using https://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//www.milanmobl.ir&w=603&h=966&a=23&s=1 couldn't find any problems just had to scroll around

Comment: i found that problem just resize your browser window even in desktop computers and scroll to right